# monit alerting - how to chain rule conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, monitoring, rules, monit

is it possible to chain a rule condition, for example,

right now I have a filesystem disk usage check

```
check filesystem test-/ with path /
  if space usage > 80% then alert
```

If I want a an alert at 80, 85, 90, 95%, I need to write 4 diff lines,

```
check filesystem test-/ with path /
  if space usage > 80% then alert
  if space usage > 85% then alert
  etc..
```

Is there a way to chain these conditions into 1 line, maybe something like this?

```
check filesystem test-/ with path /
   if space usage > 80%, 90%, 95% then alert
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible. What the goal of such thing as the alert would be triggered by the 80% metric ?

Comment: I want 3 different alerts triggered at every conditions,

once space usage is up to 80%, send out alert

lets say a week later it goes up to 85%, email another alert,

etc etc

is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: no you need to write one line by rule